# The Quintessential Quintuplets - Difference between うそうそ (uso uso) and 冗談 (じょうだん jōdan joke)

Tags: meaning, manga, anime, synonyms

From [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93612/the-quintessential-quintuplets-aka-%E4%BA%94%E7%AD%89%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E8%8A%B1%E5%AB%81-is-%E5%B1%8A%E3%81%8F%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-it-reaches-a-mondegreen)

1 - S01E01

- Related: [The Quintessential Quintuplets & Higurashi - What does it mean to repeat a word? Does たのしいたのしい means fun-filled?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/98416)

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqLeBXlNsrQ&t=156s) 2:36 - 2:44. The imouto Raiha Uesugi of the male protagonist Fuutarou Uesugi says 'うそうそ' (uso uso).

[image]

In the manga:

> [image]

2 - In S02E06

Fuutarou ('Uesugi-kun') says to h employer 'Oh, boss, you're so funny' when the employer offers a buffet to another character/s. The word used here is 冗談 (じょうだん jōdan / joudan).

[image]

In the manga

> [image]

## Questions:

1. What's the difference?
2. Also, in particular what does it mean to use 'uso' here? Like, what's the lie? Some people in fact can [live on 1 kidney](https://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/helping-you-to-decide/about-organ-donation/what-can-you-donate/about-kidney-donation/). I actually kinda think they should be reversed: Raiha is joking that Fuutarou should give up a kidney, while the boss is lying that Fuutarou will be forced to pay the for the buffet.

- **Edit**: Ok Arie says 'then proceeds to explain why the previous statement was actually a lie.' I checked the manga and apparently they do cut out dialogue in the anime adaptation. Here's full remainder of the conversation up to the stomach grumble:

> [image]

Raiha: (This part is in the anime.)

うそうそ

Raiha: (This part is NOT in the anime.)

成績悪くて困ってるって言ってたよ

でもお兄ちゃんならできるってしんじてる！

Fuutarou: (This part is NOT in the anime.)

ちょっとまって

やるなんて一言も

Raiha: (This part is in the anime.)

これでお腹いっぱい食べられるようになるね！

Translation:

> [image]

Ok so how is that an explanation of why the previous statement was a lie?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's about the original context here rather than how the meaning translates to English.

From the pictures:

In the 1st scene, the character says `うそうそ` (something like: "lying, lying") then proceeds to explain why the previous statement was actually a lie.

In the 2nd scene, `ばかり` caries the meaning of abundance of something ("nothing but"), something like: when it comes to you, boss, it's "noting but jokes".

Comment: Thanks Arie. 1 - For the 1st scene, I totally missed that the anime cut out some of their dialogue. Edited post to add their dialogue. 1A - How is the 'lie' explained please? 1B - And more important what is the lie? 2 - For the 2nd scene, well ok...what's the problem if the uso uso and joudan are reversed please? I really don't see any lie in the 1st scene, yet I see clear lies in the 2nd scene...

Comment: @BCLC sorry about the 1st. I misread the context and one of the kanji on the picture. I think you can actually use 冗談だった i the 1st example, but the nuance will change a bit (from "I just lied to you and you believed me, haha" to "Easy there, I was joking"). Small change but a change. I don't think you can use うそうそ in the 2nd tho. The guy isn't talking directly about what his boss said but about his boss's personality. A sarcastic "It's nothing but jokes with you" can't be easily changed to "you're lying" in this context.